# How to get accurate row estimate when using subquery as predicate

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, query-optimization

I have this problem in PostgreSQL(13.2) that it can't get accurate row estimate when using subquery as a predicate (it uses 0.33333 as a [default selectivity](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL_13_2/src/backend/utils/adt/selfuncs.c#L1415-L1421)). How can I get accurate row estimate for a good query plan for Q1?

I can split Q1(one query) to Q2(two queries) that get the value first, and use a second round trip to query DB, but I'm wondering is that the only way to do it. How can I avoid the second round trip?

```sql
create table t (
    id serial primary key,
    value int
);
insert into t (value) select generate_series(1, 1000000);
create index t_value on t(value);
analyze t;
```

```sql
-- Q1, estimate rows=333333
explain select * from t where value < (select value from t where id=1000000);
Index Scan using t_value on t  (cost=3.07..8317.99 rows=333333 width=8)
  Index Cond: (value < $0)
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using t_pkey on t t_1  (cost=0.42..2.64 rows=1 width=4)
          Index Cond: (id = 1000000)
```

```sql
-- Q2 estimate rows=999999
select value from t where id=1000000; -- 1000000
explain select * from t where value < 1000000;
Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..16925.00 rows=999999 width=8)
  Filter: (value < 1000000)
```

Comment: Short of rewriting the query to avoid the subquery, I don't think that there is a way.

Comment: Works fine for me: PostgreSQL version 13 with a default configuration gives me a seq scan + index scan on the subquery, as it should.

Comment: @FrankHeikens Do you get accurate estimate rows when explain?

Comment: Seq Scan on t  (cost=8.44..16933.44 rows=333333 width=8) (actual time=0.161..314.660 rows=999999 loops=1)
  Filter: (value < $0)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  Buffers: shared hit=4429
  InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
    ->  Index Scan using t_pkey on t t_1  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.105..0.107 rows=1 loops=1)
          Index Cond: (id = 1000000)
          Buffers: shared hit=4
Planning Time: 0.275 ms
Execution Time: 392.517 ms

Comment: @FrankHeikens the estimate rows is the default 0.333 of total rows, the Seq Scan you get is not based on accurate row estimate, if the total numbers change, you can get different query plans.